# HSQLDB: Insert/Get Date with java

Tags: java, sql, date, calendar, hsqldb

I'm using a HSQLDB to make a small program (with JavaFX gui) and I'm currently trying to get the "reservation" part to work (the user can add new ones or search for existing ones in a restricted period of time).
For that I already added a few dates beforehand (I'm using a database.sql script), e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO reservations(begin, end) VALUES ('2013-08-01', '2013-08-31')
```

I already wrote a few methods (create, update, delete, search, findAll) and now I'm kind of stuck on the "create" part.

I want to insert new reservations into the DB with

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO reservations(begin, end) VALUES (?,?)");
```

but I'm having problems creating new Dates that I can insert.

```
pstmt.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) beg);
```

Doesn't work (I'm using java.util.Date objects to save the exported dates from the DB), it just aborts my tests (jUnit).

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(2014, 0, 1);
Date beginn = cal1.getTime();
```

only creates dates in the form of: Wed Jan 01 12:23:15 CET 2014

But (and I don't know how exactly dates are saved in HSQLDB) I want the date to be "YYYY-MM-DD".

So, what's the best way of converting the calendar dates into the format I need (and caste them? Unfortunately, casting a String to Date doesn't work). And: Is my approach of using java.util.Date dates okay if I'm going to use JavaFX to let the user select a starting and an end date?

Comment: I'm now experiencing another problem: a.equals(b) won't return "true"........a is "Date a = new java.sql.Date(r.getBegin().getTime());" with r being a new instance of reservation........b is "b = rs.getDate("begin");" (using a Statement & ResultSet rs with "SELECT begin, end FROM reservation"........ It should return "true" since I first create r, commit it to the DB (which is working perfectly) and then use it with "find(r)" but still it doesn't, so there has to be a problem with the dates (already checked, the "find" method works for everything except the dates)... :/ Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Yup, what I expected...a.getTime()=1388603443625 but b.getTime()=1388530800000 .... ToString() returns the same (2014-01-01) for both a and b (at least it's the same day), so I guess this is happening because of Calendar? Isn't there a way to only set the h, min & sec to 0, so both Dates are the same? The only thing that I've found so far and that includes those is "set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)" but it looks like there's no way to just set h, min and sec?!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(java.sql.Date) beg` causing a `ClassCastException` you should write:

```
new java.sql.Date(beg.getTime()); // provided beg is of type java.util.Date as you wrote
```

If you use strings in VALUES-clause you might consider [JDBC-escape-syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefjdbcescapedate.html) for dates. And your statement "only creates dates in the form of: Wed Jan 01 12:23:15 CET 2014" does not matter at all because you only see the output of method `toString()`of `java.util.Date`. It is not relevant for the internal state or storage in db. Your wish "I want the date to be "YYYY-MM-DD"." is rather relevant for representation layer of your application, not for the internal storage format of db which you have no control about other than choosing the appropriate db column type (here: ANSI-SQL-DATE).

In the representation layer you can use classes like `SimpleDateFormat`with pattern "yyyy-MM-dd" for the output you wish.

**EDIT (because of questions in comments):**

Okay, you really don't need to worry about the `toString()`-representation of a `java.util.Date`-timestamp. Its internal state is only a long representing the elapsed millis since 1970-01-01 not counting leap seconds. Just ignore the standard output of java.util.Date which rather displays the system zone context but not so much the internal state. Using `a.before(b)` is quite okay and has nothing to do with the weird output of `toString()`-method of `java.util.Date`.

Furthermore: You have no real control about how your database tool displays the date column values. That is the secret of the tool you use. The internal state inside db might be quite different so every db is like a kind of black box.

But when you read the date values from db and present the data to the user then and exactly then you have to worry about the representation of the `java.util.Date`-objects. For this purpose I have recommended to use `SimpleDateFormat` - see above. But this adaptation (conversion to readable human date format) is not in db-tool, not in the JDBC-layer, but only in user-representation layer, normally in UI.

Comment: No, I'm using DATE in den DB: "CREATE TABLE reservation (resid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, begin DATE NOT NULL, end DATE NOT NULL)" .................. I'm going to use the JavaFX scene builder to make the layout and I just want it to work out with the calendar drop downs from it (so users can chose a period they want to search in). What do you think: Is it better to use java.util.Date and cast it to java.sql.Date or should I use the latter one right from the start?

Comment: @Neph What I have written, use `java.sql.Date` for db (in your `PreparedStatement`), but not with type-cast!

Comment: @Neph You use `java.sql.Date` only inside your JDBC-layer that is as parameter in your `PreparedStatement`. Outside you can use `java.util.Date` (although I consider it as broken, but this is quite another topic). And again: Don't cast, but wrap.

Comment: The thing about the looks is: if I use logger.info() (should be from log4j) on the java.sql.Date it outputs "2014-01-01", java.util.Date on the other hand outputs the whole thing including the name of the day, hours, minutes and seconds and since I have to compare the chosen date and the date in the db (using a.before(b) from java.util.Date), I'm worried that it won't work because it looks like the java version saves a lot more information. And yes, I want to output all the reservations in a table with begin/end in their own columns and in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: So from what I understand: "public ArrayList<Reservation> search(Date a, Date b)" (I'm creating instances of it in e.g. the test classes and in the service class) should be java.sql.dates and before committing a and b to the "search" method I should wrap them in the e.g. test class with java.sql.Date a=new java.sql.Date(a1), with a1 being Date a1 = cal1.getTime();  right?

Comment: @Neph see my edit, and don't use `java.sql.Date` outside of the JDBC-layer.

Comment: Okay, going to commit util.Dates then (to "search(Date a, Date b)") and wrapping them in java.sql.Dates there. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I'm now experiencing another problem: a.equals(b) won't return "true"........a is "Date a = new java.sql.Date(r.getBegin().getTime());" with r being a new instance of reservation........b is "b = rs.getDate("begin");" (using a Statement & ResultSet rs with "SELECT begin, end FROM reservation"........ It should return "true" since I first create r, commit it to the DB (which is working perfectly) and then use it with "find(r)" but still it doesn't, so there has to be a problem with the dates (already checked, the "find" method works for everything except the dates)... :/ Any idea what is wrong?